# How to limit number of frames when exporting Aftereffects as image sequence?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

I am very new to Aftereffects and need to know - I have succeeded in exporting my animation as an image sequence (the setting PNG sequence) but it exports A LOT of images, because it is exporting one for each frame, which is great.

Problem is for my project i don't need every frame, and cant have as many images. Without going through and only taking the ones I want, can I limit the number of frames/images Aftereffects exports when I export as image sequence?

Comment: Yes, you can but only in a sequence wise. i-e you can render only from 100 to 200 frames. Its up to you just go through the settings panel and you'll find all the desired answers you need

Answer (score 0):

**BE CAREFUL: I'M USING AFTER EFFECTS CS4 ('coz I'm broke). YOUR WINDOWS MAY VARY TO MINE (I hope it doesn't). YOU'VE BEEN WARNED.**

When dealing with long compositions, you could always resize your **Work Area** and **Trim Comp to Work Area**, making your animations shorter **but when you're not careful, it might cut some animation either in the beginning or the end of the comp.**

Since I don't know if you've found your way out of things, pictures are provided

[image: Right Click Work Area, Above the Timeline > Trim Comp to Work Area]

You could also do this on **Render Settings** on the **Render Queue Tab > Render Settings > Time Sampling Box > The "Custom" button at the right of the Start, End, Duration Times**

[image: View of the Custom Time Span Window]

You could also reduce your **FPS (frames per second)** in the **Render Settings** at the **Render Queue Tab (you need to add the comp to the render queue)** but when you'll render these into a full video, **you might notice constant stutters as if it was laggy.**

[image: Render Settings Picture]

You could also change it in the **Composition Settings** in the **Composition > Composition Settings** albeit a more **destructive** method

[image: Comp Settings Picture]

Mix these things together, and you'll reduce your rendered images even more. **Be careful though.**

I'm new here and I don't know the standards of answering questions. I hope this helps you and good luck with your project!